# Recommendation system to recommend similar companies

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommendation system based on which industries they belong and what kind of work they do.
eg. Microsoft, Apple and Google should show similar results,
Tesla, General Motors, BMW should show similar results
where can i find data for the following which gives me some description of the companies and also what industries they belong to.

Comment: https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/industries.aspx has lists of industries and sub-industries (for companies listed on the NASDAQ)

Answer (score 0):

[This dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/ash316/forbes-top-2000-companies/home) and the similar datasets on Kaggle should help.